# Browser side code editor component

Tags: javascript, flash, silverlight, applet, javafx

do you know any browser-side component, in **HTML/Javascript**, **Flash**, **Applet** or **Silverlight**, that
would allow source code edition with **syntax highlighting** and **auto-completion**.

[CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/) has a good syntax highlighting support but does not seem to support auto-completion.

If no such editor exists do you know any way to implement auto-completion using HTML and javascript or any other browser-side technology ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [Bespin](https://mozillalabs.com/bespin/).  It is an open source html 5 based IDE.  I don't know how hard it would be to extract just the editor component, but it sounds promising.

Comment: Wow, very interesting.
I'm going to test it as soon as possible.
Thanks a lot Jay for this great input.